# Unable to understand the following code. How does the following code create a positive definite matrix

Tags: c, algorithm

```
//Cannot understand use of this function

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            double sum = 0;
            for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {
                //Why is i*n+k used here?
                sum += A[i*n+k]*A[j*n+k];
            }
            C[i*n+j] = sum;

int main() {
    

    double *m4 = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n*n);
//Why was gemm_ATA function used here?
    gemm_ATA(m3, m4, n); //make a positive-definite matrix
    printf("\n");
    //show_matrix(m4,n);

    
    
}
```

I am making a project for parallelizing Cholesky method and found a useful code. In the given, project this function is used and I have no idea why is it used.
Also, can someone help me understand the code and its function used in the code given in the link:-
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f5750c20d456da9

Comment: The indexing is used to retrieve data from the input _as if_ it were transposed, but without actually tranposing it.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: OT: regarding:  `double *m3 = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n*n);` 1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)  Suggest removing that cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` and `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`.  also note that the function: `malloc()` expects a `size_t` parameter, not `int`

Answer (score 0):

The function `gemm_ATA` takes an input matrix `A` and calculates `C = A^T * A`, which is positive semi-definite by definition (note the semi-definiteness, depending on the properties of the input matrix).

Mathematically, calculating this matrix would be:

```
c_i,j = sum_k  a_k,i * a_k,j
```

`c_i,j` is the entry of `C` in the `i`-th row and `j`-th column. The expressions `i*n+k` and `j*n+k` transform these 2D indices (row and column) to a 1D index of the underlying array.

Answer (score 0):

`gemm_ATA` calculate `AA^T` and stores it in `C`. `A^T` is `A` but flipped over its diagonal. So `A*A^T` multiply each row of matrix A (call `A[-,i]`) with each column of the matrix A (call `A^T[j,-]`) which is also the row of A (`A[-,j]`). 
Also, if you flatten an n*n 2D matrix to 1D matrix, you can access the first element of each *i-th* row by `i*n+0`. So if you want *k-th* column of ith row you have it with `A[i*n+k]`.
Note that since you pass `C` by reference to your function, after calling the function, `m4` is your positive definite matrix created from `m3`.